# Passing an Id to a AlertDialog click event

Tags: java, android

I have a mapview with pointers, when a pointer is clicked I show an alertdialog.
In this dialog I have a bit of text and two buttons, a positive and negative.
When the positive is clicked I want to open a new activity based on the id of the pointer clicked.

I am new to Android and  java and I am having trouble passing the ID to the click event.

My code so far..

```
       List<myItemType> myItems= //code to get list of items
                final ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>(

    );

            for (myItemType item : myItems) {

            Double lat = Double.parseDouble(item .Lat);
            Double lng = Double.parseDouble(item .Long);

            items.add(new OverlayItem(item .ID, item .Name, item .Description
                    .substring(0, 20) + "...", new GeoPoint(lat, lng)));
        }
    ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> myOverLay = 
            new ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>(
                this, items, this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.standard_pointer), new Point(5, 5),
                HotspotPlace.BOTTOM_CENTER, new ItemizedOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index,final OverlayItem item) {

                        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapActivity.this);

                        dialog.setTitle(item.mTitle);
                        dialog.setMessage(item.mDescription);
                        dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.View,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                        {

//********************CLICK EVENT HERE
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                                        Intent i = new Intent(MapActivity.this,POI.class);
                                        i.putExtra("Id", item.mKey); //<------ item.mKey is null!
                                        startActivity(i);
                                    }
                        });
                        dialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.Cancel, null);
                        dialog.create();
                        dialog.show();

                        return true;
                    }
```

The Id is stored in the "item.mKey", I know I can't access it directly, but I can't work out how to pass it in.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Bex

Comment: Where did you assign anything to item.mKey?

Comment: It's in the newoverlayitem, it's item.ID

Comment: Can you show us the `newoverlayitem` constructor?

Comment: It's part of the OSMDroid custom mapview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add an answer to how I did it.. I added a global variable to use rather than pass in the ID.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your mKey is a String, try this out. Write `final String key = item.mkey;` before `dialog.setPositiveButton` and then in the `onClick` method `i.putExtra("Id", key);`

Comment: I tried this, but changed it to an int, but either way it doesn't recognise the variable key! Any other ideas?

Comment: did you cast the `item` variable to `newoverlayitem` type ?

Comment: The item is null, I have set it as a global variable now as couldn't think of another way.. not the best but works